# Allow users to moves files into a "readonly" directory

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have users who work on Jupyter notebooks in their own home directories, and then they can move the notebook onto a shared directory on the Jupyter server where everyone can read them, but not edit or delete them. Only the owner should be able to delete and edit.

I tried to work with the setgid and sticky bits, and the last issue I have is that if the file has `664` permissions, I don't see a way to change it to `644` so only the owner can change it.

Comment: have a look at https://bindfs.org

Answer (score 0):

This can (probably) be done with default ACLs. On the directory to which the files are uploaded (that may not be the one where they appear in the end) you have to configure this:

```
setfacl -m d:g::rx /path/to/dir
setfacl -m d:o::rx /path/to/dir
```

Comment: I tried with the ACL on the `readonly` directory but then when the file is moved from the home of the user to the `readonly` directory, the permissions are still `664` and the ACL seems to not be inherited.

Comment: If the tool they use to copy or move the file changes the permission bits based on the original, the default ACL doesn't really help against that.

Comment: @TheProphet Default ACL do not work if a file is moved within a filesystem. They only work on file creation (including copying). So you would have to set these ACL within the home directory. But an inotify solution (or even cron) might be better: Just create the files with the wrong permissions and then fix them. Or you take the target directory out of the home directory filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for clarifying. Sounds like you want everyone in the group to be able to add files, and upon adding the files, their permission becomes 644. I recommend using `incron` to execute `chmod` at file system event of `IN_CREATE`

To be specific, edit crontab `incrontab -e`, and add your triggering event:

`~/readonlyDirectory IN_CREATE customScript.sh $#`

Then create the `customScript.sh` that change the permission of the new files:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 644 $1
```

---

Original answer:

You must be the owner or a super user to change this file. You need to talk to the owner and let them run the command `chmod 664 filename` or talk to the system admin to raise your privilege to run `sudo chmod 664 filename`.

If they don't allow you to do either, then there is a good reason that you are not supposed to write into that directory.

Comment: I am the admin, trying to setup a system with a readonly directory where my users can drop files so they are not editable by anyone else, even if the file had `g+w` before.